# Why is this function not deleting many rows at once correctly?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

This function works with a little bit of data, but not with hundreds of rows and I wonder if I'm missing some `Spreadsheet.flush()` or something of this nature.

```
const values = [["2022-12-31T06:00:00.000Z"],["2022-12-31T06:00:00.000Z"],["2022-12-31T06:00:00.000Z"],["2022-12-31T06:00:00.000Z"],["2022-12-31T06:00:00.000Z"],["2022-12-31T06:00:00.000Z"],["2022-12-31T06:00:00.000Z"],["2022-12-31T06:00:00.000Z"],["2022-12-31T06:00:00.000Z"],["2022-12-31T06:00:00.000Z"],["2022-12-31T06:00:00.000Z"],["2022-12-31T06:00:00.000Z"]];

function DeleteRows(sheetName, year) {
  sheetName = 'Saved Budgets'//For tests
  year = '2022' //For tests
  var SS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName); //Get Open Lines Sheet
  var lastRow = SS.getLastRow();
  var range = SS.getRange(2, 1, lastRow - 1, 1); //get range
  range.sort({ column: 1, ascending: false }) // filter data descending   

  var firstRowToDelete = 0;
  var numOfRows = 1;  // starting row to be increment and become the number of rows       
  var values = range.getValues();//Got it for comparison

  for (let a = 0; a < values.length; a++) {
    let dt = new Date(values[a]).getFullYear();
    if (dt == year) {
      firstRowToDelete = parseInt(a);
      numOfRows++
    }
  }
  if (numOfRows != 1) {
    numOfRows = numOfRows - 1 // minus 1 to get the last row
    SS.deleteRows(firstRowToDelete, numOfRows);
  }
  range.sort({ column: 1, ascending: true }) // filter data again ascending
}
```

Comment: Just wanted to clarify on this, but the script you have provided is intended to delete row data that has the year 2022, is that correct?

Comment: Please describe what the function works, i.e. what is the purpose of the global variable `values` and the local variable `values`.

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your goal, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not useful and I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Comment: I) `firstRowToDelete` is overwritten every time `dt == year`, II) `deleteRows` is used but matching rows are not guaranteed to be consecutive (unless they are already sorted), III) `a` starts from `0` but row starts from `2` that you should add the offset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to delete rows that the column "A" is `year = '2022'`, `firstRowToDelete = parseInt(a);` is the last index of the rows that the column "A" is `year = '2022'`. And, `numOfRows` is the number of rows. In this case, I'm worried that all rows that the column "A" is `year = '2022'` cannot be deleted. And also, when the values are large, the rows for deleting might be over the bottom of the sheet, and/or `range` of `range.sort({ column: 1, ascending: true })` might be over the bottom of the sheet. I thought that this might be the reason for your issue.

If you want to remove this issue, when your script is modified, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
for (let a = 0; a < values.length; a++) {
  let dt = new Date(values[a]).getFullYear();
  if (dt == year) {
    firstRowToDelete = parseInt(a);
    numOfRows++
  }
}
if (numOfRows != 1) {
  numOfRows = numOfRows - 1 // minus 1 to get the last row
  SS.deleteRows(firstRowToDelete, numOfRows);
}
range.sort({ column: 1, ascending: true }) // filter data again ascending
```

#### To:

```
for (let a = 0; a < values.length; a++) {
  let dt = new Date(values[a]).getFullYear();
  if (dt == year) {
    if (firstRowToDelete == 0) firstRowToDelete = a + 2; // Modified
    numOfRows++
  }
}
if (numOfRows != 1) {
  numOfRows = numOfRows - 1;
  SS.deleteRows(firstRowToDelete, numOfRows);
}
SS.getRange(2, 1, SS.getLastRow() - 1, 1).sort({ column: 1, ascending: true }); // Modified
```

As another modification, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
var values = range.getValues();//Got it for comparison

for (let a = 0; a < values.length; a++) {
  let dt = new Date(values[a]).getFullYear();
  if (dt == year) {
    firstRowToDelete = parseInt(a);
    numOfRows++
  }
}
if (numOfRows != 1) {
  numOfRows = numOfRows - 1 // minus 1 to get the last row
  SS.deleteRows(firstRowToDelete, numOfRows);
}
range.sort({ column: 1, ascending: true }) // filter data again ascending
```

#### To:

```
var values = range.getDisplayValues();
var numOfRows = values.filter(([a]) => new Date(a).getFullYear() == year).length;
if (numOfRows > 0) {
  var firstRowToDelete = values.findIndex(([a]) => new Date(a).getFullYear() == year);
  SS.deleteRows(firstRowToDelete > -1 ? firstRowToDelete + 2 : firstRowToDelete, numOfRows);
}
SS.getRange(2, 1, SS.getLastRow() - 1, 1).sort({ column: 1, ascending: true });
```

Comment: I read a bit on ```filter()``` performance and it seems to be slower than a ```for loop```, but since the data set won't be too large (<5k rows), it doesn't affect much.
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

**NOTE:** This is all based on the assumption that the `values` global variable is actually a data in the spreadsheet, and you would want to remove all data with 2022.

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet(); //you can change this to specify a specific sheet
  var range = ss.getRange(2,1,ss.getLastRow(), ss.getLastColumn());
  var values = range.getValues();
  var year = /2022/; // change this to filter other years
  var newval = values.filter(x=>year.test(x) ? null : x); 
  console.log(newval); //to check if it populates the correct data during logging. 
  range.clearContent(); //clears the data based on the current range keeping the formatting. 
  var newrange = ss.getRange(2,1,newval.length, ss.getLastColumn()); //creates a new range based on the size of `newval`
  newrange.setValues(newval); 
}
```

**Explanation:**

1. `var range = ss.getRange(2,1,ss.getLastRow(), ss.getLastColumn());` gets the current data on the spreadsheet, including the columns.
2. Using `var values = range.getValues();` we get a 2D array structure of the data on the spreadsheet.
3. Using `filter()` and `test()` method on `var newval = values.filter(x=>year.test(x) ? null : x);`  using a ternary operator to test whether an array element contains the year to filter out.
4. `range.clearContent();` to delete the contents of the range.
5. `var newrange = ss.getRange(2,1,newval.length, ss.getLastColumn());` creates a new range based on the new array.
6. `newrange.setValues(newval);` sets the new value on the spreadsheet

**Screenshots:**

**NOTE:** Multiple columns in the data are for testing to see dynamic deletion even if there is additional data on the columns.

**Initial data:**

[image]

**After running the script:**

[image]

**Execution duration:**

[image]

**References:**

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#clearContent()
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Edited as recommended on the post also on the inline comments of the script. Thanks @TheMaster

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer and the detailed explanation. Rather then clearing the range, I guess the complaxity really boils down to finding the 1st row and the last to be deleted dynamically. Again, thanks!